# How can I get IWebElement from dictionary<string, IWebElement>

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, automation

I should add element to elementCache, where string => locator(e.g. xpath or id of element) and when I repeat some action method FindElement will be using IWebElement from dictionary

````
Dictionary<string, IWebElemebnt> elementCache = new();

public bool IsEnableElement(UiElement locator)
{
   if(locator.IsVisible())
   {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}

public IWebElement FindElement(UiElement locator)
{
   if(IsEnableElement(locator)
   {
      //return IWebElement;
   }
   else
   {
      var webElement = FindElementInParent(FindParent(locator), locator.By);

      elementCache.Add(locator.ToString(), webElement);

      return webElement;  
   }
   // check dictionary if the element exists in the dictionary, then return 
   //IWebElement, otherwise find and add to the dictionary and return it
}```
````

Comment: What is the dictionary key? Presumably you put items into a dictionary so that you can look them up by key, right?

Comment: Dictionary key is xpath, Yes, you are right

Answer (score 1):

You need to use locator as a key. Then you can use it to lookup in the dictionary. Sth like this  :

```
public IWebElement IsEnableElement(string locator)
{
     if (elementCache.ContainsKey(locator ?? "") && elementCache[key].Key == locator) 
        {
           return elementCache[locator].Value;
        }
}
```